# Mongodb cluster setting

Tags: juju, maas

I have installed Mongodb using the instructions After setting it up, I can see all my services exposed but I still get the message: this db does not have sharding enabled ... when I run the sh.status() command from the mongo shell. Also, when I connect to mongos from the shell, I do not get a "mongos>" prompt, I just get the ">" prompt. I do not know how to go about resolving the problem.

I have 5 nodes. I use node 1 as my mongos, and node 2 as my config server (running 3 instances). The configuration for node 3, 4, and 5 are as follows: Node 3: shard1/0, shard2/1, shard3/2. Node 4: shard2/0, shard3/1, shard1/2 and Node 5 shard3/0,shard1/1, shard2/1.

What could be the problem

Comment: Make Sure that all Nodes are reachable to each other.

Comment: I have added the relations between the mongos and config servers as well as the mongos and shards. Is there any other way this should be done?

Comment: Still no answer. I used the method on this link http://blog.xtremeghost.com/2012/11/lets-shard-something.html but something seems to be missing.

Answer (score 0):

I found one bug in in the mongodb charm's hooks.py script. On line 1053, we see a call to enable_configuresvr function:

```
enable_configsvr(config_data['config_server_port'])
```

However, enable_configuresvr's function parameter list does not match:

```
def enable_configsvr(config_data, wait_for=default_wait_for,
                 max_tries=default_max_tries):
```

The config_data['config_server_port'] shouldn't be the parameter passed; config_data should be.

The same problem is on line 1069 with enable_mongos passing config_data['mongos_port'] instead of config_data.

I'll try to run some tests to confirm these are the only bugs.

Outside of filling a bug report, has anyone else experienced this problem? It seems like it should be more wide-spread that just Conrad and me :P

Answer (score 0):

Conrad, I haven't yet ran the test with the corrections I commented on above but it might also solve the log file issue you mentioned most recently.

Juju is still very valuable. I'm hoping my bug catch fixes the problem we are experiencing and allows us to deploy our sharded mongo cluster correctly. With Juju, we'll be able to scale horizontally very easily.

I'm also using Juju to deploy our custom php charm (install php, hooks into Apache to setup a vhost, and places the our php files in the right directory) that I want to cohabitate with each mongos instance. When changes are made to our production php files, we'll be able to update the charm, and all the nodes running the charm, with an juj update-charm command.

I haven't come across anything that's Open Source, and mature enough, that is as much hands off as Juju yet. I tested foreman and puppet already before settling in on Maas and Juju.

Answer (score 0):

I had more time to investigate and run some tests. I can't see how this code has been in the wild for years. Are we missing something? Not only are there incorrect parameter values I already posted about but it appears that there is a logic bug as well.

I believe the reason the congifsvr and mongos units are not assuming their identities is because enable_configsvr and enable_mongos are never actually called! They are both in an if block that requires there already be a running configsvr and mongos (respectively). Neither are, but there is no other place in the code that actually instantiates configsvr and mongos.

How does can enable_configsvr execute when the if statement is never satisfied? (line 1050 of hooks.py)

```
if configsvr_pid is not None:
    configsvr_port = re.search('--port (\w+)', configsvr_cmd_line).group(2)
    disable_configsvr(configsvr_port)
    enable_configsvr(config_data['config_server_port'])
else:
    open_port(config_data['config_server_port'])
```

Same logic applies to enable_mongos on line 1066:

```
    if mongos_pid is not None:
    mongos_port = re.search('--port (\w+)', mongos_cmd_line).group(1)
    disable_mongos(mongos_port)
    enable_mongos(config_data['mongos_port'])
else:
    open_port(config_data['mongos_port'])
```

I did post a bug report here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/charms/+source/mongodb/+bug/1460876

Has anyone successfully deployed a sharded mongo cluster using the charm?